# Jersey CRUD - Update and Post doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey

It's the first time that a Java Service class doesn't work correctly for me and I don't know the reason.

I have over 20 service classes and all except this one work perfectly:

```html
package it.jack.fdd.services;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import it.jack.fdd.dao.FactoryDao;
import it.jack.fdd.domain.Feedback;
import it.jack.fdd.domain.Staff;
import it.jack.fdd.domain.StaffType;
import it.jack.fdd.dto.StaffDto;
import it.jack.fdd.dto.StaffTypeDto;
import it.jack.fdd.dto.TokenStaffDto;
import it.jack.fdd.util.ConverterDTO;

@Path("/feedback")
public class FeedbackServices {
 
 @GET
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public List<Feedback> getFeedback() {
 
        List<Feedback> listOfFeedback = FactoryDao.getIstance().createBaseDao().getAll(Feedback.class);
   return listOfFeedback;
  
 }
 
 @GET
 @Path("/notread")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public List<Feedback> getFeedbackNoRead(@HeaderParam("token") String token) {
  TokenStaffDto ts = new TokenStaffDto();
  StaffDto s = new StaffDto();
  StaffTypeDto st = new StaffTypeDto();
  
  
  Boolean ex = FactoryDao.getIstance().createTokenStaffDao().getExistence(token);
  ts = ConverterDTO.converterTokenStafftoDTO(FactoryDao.getIstance().createTokenStaffDao().getTokenStaffFromToken(token));
  s = ConverterDTO.converterStafftoDTO((Staff) FactoryDao.getIstance().createBaseDao().getById(ts.getIdtokenStaff(), Staff.class));
  st = ConverterDTO.converterStaffTypetoDTO( (StaffType) FactoryDao.getIstance().createBaseDao().getById(s.getStaffType().getIdstaffType(),
    StaffType.class));

  if (ex && st.getIdstaffType() == 1) { 
   List<Feedback> listOfFeedback = FactoryDao.getIstance().createFeedbackDao().notRead();
   return listOfFeedback;
  }else
   return null;
  
 }
 
 @GET
 @Path("/{id}")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Object getFeedbackById(@PathParam("id") int id, @HeaderParam("token") String token) {
  TokenStaffDto ts = new TokenStaffDto();
  StaffDto s = new StaffDto();
  StaffTypeDto st = new StaffTypeDto();
  
  
  Boolean ex = FactoryDao.getIstance().createTokenStaffDao().getExistence(token);
  ts = ConverterDTO.converterTokenStafftoDTO(FactoryDao.getIstance().createTokenStaffDao().getTokenStaffFromToken(token));
  s = ConverterDTO.converterStafftoDTO((Staff) FactoryDao.getIstance().createBaseDao().getById(ts.getIdtokenStaff(), Staff.class));
  st = ConverterDTO.converterStaffTypetoDTO( (StaffType) FactoryDao.getIstance().createBaseDao().getById(s.getStaffType().getIdstaffType(),
    StaffType.class));

  if (ex && st.getIdstaffType() == 1) { 
   return FactoryDao.getIstance().createBaseDao().getById(id, Feedback.class);
  }else
   return null;
 }
 
 @POST
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public int addFeedback(Feedback feedback/*, @HeaderParam("token") String token*/) {

   return FactoryDao.getIstance().createBaseDao().save(feedback);

 }

 @PUT
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public void updateFeedback(Feedback feedback) {

   FactoryDao.getIstance().createBaseDao().update(feedback);


 }

}
```

all this methods except @PUT and @POST work perfectly. In fact @GET methods works. My domain class about this class is called "Feedback.java":

```html
package it.jack.fdd.domain;
// Generated 30-nov-2016 0.17.09 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1.Final

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Feedback generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "feedback", catalog = "fdd_dbproducts")
public class Feedback implements java.io.Serializable {

 private Integer idfeedback;
 private User user;
 private String message;
 private boolean read;

 public Feedback() {
 }

 public Feedback(User user, String message, boolean read) {
  this.user = user;
  this.message = message;
  this.read = read;
 }

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

 @Column(name = "idfeedback", unique = true, nullable = false)
 public Integer getIdfeedback() {
  return this.idfeedback;
 }

 public void setIdfeedback(Integer idfeedback) {
  this.idfeedback = idfeedback;
 }

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "fkuser_feedback", nullable = false)
 public User getUser() {
  return this.user;
 }

 public void setUser(User user) {
  this.user = user;
 }

 @Column(name = "message", nullable = false, length = 45)
 public String getMessage() {
  return this.message;
 }

 public void setMessage(String message) {
  this.message = message;
 }

 @Column(name = "read", nullable = false)
 public boolean isRead() {
  return this.read;
 }

 public void setRead(boolean read) {
  this.read = read;
 }

}
```

this is my factory classes called FactoryDao:

```html
package it.jack.fdd.dao;

import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.AccTypeDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.BaseDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.CapacityDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.CategoryDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.DispenserDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.FamilyDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.FeedbackDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.GeoAreaDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.IndustryDaoImpl;
//import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.InnerDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.ProducerDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.ProductDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.ProductDescDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.RtDispenserCategoryDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.RtFamilyProductDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.RtIngredientProductDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.RtStaffDispenserDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.StaffDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.StaffLoginDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.StaffTypeDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.TokenStaffDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.AccTypeDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.BaseDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.CapacityDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.CategoryDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.DispenserDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.FamilyDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.FeedbackDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.GeoAreaDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.IndustryDao;
//import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.InnerDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.ProducerDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.ProductDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.ProductDescDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.RtDispenserCategoryDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.RtFamilyProductDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.RtIngredientProductDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.RtStaffDispenserDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.StaffDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.StaffLoginDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.StaffTypeDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.TokenStaffDao;

public class FactoryDao {
 //SINGLETON
 private FactoryDao() {
  
 }
 
 static class Holder {
  static public final FactoryDao ISTANCE = new FactoryDao();
 }
 
 private BaseDao basedao = new BaseDaoImpl();
 private DispenserDao dispenserdao = new DispenserDaoImpl();
 private GeoAreaDao geoareadao = new GeoAreaDaoImpl();
 private ProductDao productdao = new ProductDaoImpl();
 private RtIngredientProductDao rtingredientproductdao = new RtIngredientProductDaoImpl();
 private StaffDao staffdao = new StaffDaoImpl();
 private StaffLoginDao stafflogindao = new StaffLoginDaoImpl();
 private StaffTypeDao stafftypedao = new StaffTypeDaoImpl();
 private TokenStaffDao tokenstaffdao = new TokenStaffDaoImpl();
 private ProductDescDao productdescdao = new ProductDescDaoImpl();
 private ProducerDao producerdao = new ProducerDaoImpl();
 private FamilyDao familydao = new FamilyDaoImpl();
 private RtFamilyProductDao rtfamilyproductdao = new RtFamilyProductDaoImpl();
 private CategoryDao categorydao = new CategoryDaoImpl();
 private RtDispenserCategoryDao rtdispensercategorydao = new RtDispenserCategoryDaoImpl();
 private RtStaffDispenserDao rtstaffdispenserdao = new RtStaffDispenserDaoImpl();
 private IndustryDao industrydao = new IndustryDaoImpl();
 private CapacityDao capacitydao = new CapacityDaoImpl();
 private AccTypeDao acctypedao = new AccTypeDaoImpl();
 private FeedbackDao feedbackdao = new FeedbackDaoImpl();
 

 public BaseDao createBaseDao(){
  return basedao;
 }
 
 public DispenserDao createDispenserDao(){
  return dispenserdao;
 }
 
 public GeoAreaDao createGeoAreaDao(){
  return geoareadao;
 }
 
 public ProductDao createProductDao(){
  return productdao;
 }
 
 public RtIngredientProductDao createRtIngredientProductDao(){
  return rtingredientproductdao;
 }
 
 public StaffDao createStaffDao(){
  return staffdao;
 }
 
 public StaffLoginDao createStaffLoginDao(){
  return stafflogindao;
 }
 
 public StaffTypeDao createStaffTypeDao(){
  return stafftypedao;
 }
 
 public TokenStaffDao createTokenStaffDao(){
  return tokenstaffdao;
 }
 
 public ProductDescDao createProductDescDao(){
  return productdescdao;
 }
 
 public ProducerDao createProducerDao(){
  return producerdao;
 }
 
 public FamilyDao createFamilyDao(){
  return familydao;
 }
 
 public RtFamilyProductDao createRtFamilyProductDao(){
  return rtfamilyproductdao;
 }
 
 public CategoryDao createCategoryDao(){
  return categorydao;
 }
 
 public RtDispenserCategoryDao createRtDispenserCategoryDao(){
  return rtdispensercategorydao;
 }
 
 public RtStaffDispenserDao createRtStaffDispenserDao(){
  return rtstaffdispenserdao;
 }
 
 public IndustryDao createIndustryDao(){
  return industrydao;
 }
  
 public CapacityDao createCapacityDao(){
  return capacitydao;
 }
 
 public AccTypeDao createAccTypeDao(){
  return acctypedao;
 }
 
 public FeedbackDao createFeedbackDao(){
  return feedbackdao;
 }
 
 public  static FactoryDao getIstance() {
  return Holder.ISTANCE;
 }

}
```

(I do not need to include implementations based methods update and insert, as with other classes work)

For example, I try my GET METHOD, I have this JSON file:

```html
[
  {
    "idfeedback": 1,
    "user": {
      "iduser": 1,
      "name": "Andrea",
      "surname": "Pirlo",
      "birthDate": "1980-12-12",
      "cityResidence": "Cannole",
      "provinceResidence": "Lecce",
      "postalCode": "73020",
      "gender": true,
      "bankAccounts": [],
      "userLogin": {
        "iduserLogin": 1,
        "email": "ciao96@libero.it",
        "pass": "asdasd5sada5adsdsadasdas6dsa6da5dadad",
        "tokenUser": null
      }
    },
    "message": "migliorare controlli",
    "read": false
  },
  {
    "idfeedback": 2,
    "user": {
      "iduser": 1,
      "name": "Andrea",
      "surname": "Pirlo",
      "birthDate": "1980-12-12",
      "cityResidence": "Cannole",
      "provinceResidence": "Lecce",
      "postalCode": "73020",
      "gender": true,
      "bankAccounts": [],
      "userLogin": {
        "iduserLogin": 1,
        "email": "ciao96@libero.it",
        "pass": "asdasd5sada5adsdsadasdas6dsa6da5dadad",
        "tokenUser": null
      }
    },
    "message": "sdfsdf",
    "read": false
  }
]
```

I want to edit the first item in this way:

```html
{
    "idfeedback": 1,
    "user": {
      "iduser": 1,
      "name": "Andrea",
      "surname": "Pirlo",
      "birthDate": "1980-12-12",
      "cityResidence": "Cannole",
      "provinceResidence": "Lecce",
      "postalCode": "73020",
      "gender": true,
      "bankAccounts": [],
      "userLogin": {
        "iduserLogin": 1,
        "email": "ciao96@libero.it",
        "pass": "asdasd5sada5adsdsadasdas6dsa6da5dadad",
        "tokenUser": null
      }
    },
    "message": "update",
    "read": true
  }
```

the response is 204 (it's ok) but nothing happened:
[image]
[image]

I don't understand what is the reason.

Comment: I can see you using @produces at post and put type request,  why? But convention is annotation consumes for post or put type request.

Comment: Sorry, I solved this..now I answer with the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem whas because "read". "read" is also a mySql's system variable. Solved renaming it